Difference between Gopal shashtranam and Vishnu sahashtranam
What is the distinction between the Gopala Sahasranama and the Vishnu Sahasranama? In the Anushasana Parva of Mahabharata, Bhishma explained the Vishnu Sahasranama to Yudhishthira. However, I’m unsure of the exact origin of the Gopala Sahasranama. Are the two texts the same or different?

Both are separate prayers.
The Gopal Sahasranama is spoken by Lord Shiva to Parvati which glories Sri Radha-Krishna. Sample verse:

näda-bindu-kalätitash chatur-varga-phala-pradah sushumnä-märga-sancäri
dehasyäntara-samsthitah
He is the näda-bindu letter (näda-bindu-kalätita). He gives the
results of the four vargas (chatur-varga-phala-prada). He travels on
the Sushumnä path (sushumnä-märga-sancäri). He is the Supersoul in the
body of every conditioned soul (dehasyäntara-samsthita).

Gopala Sahasranamam from the Sammohana Tantra
